# Powershell scripts runs when copied into Powershell but not when clicked on

Tags: powershell

I'm extremely new to Powershell and just wanted to create a simple command I can throw into the task scheduler in order to backup a folder. I tried a simple command in the powershell and it works fine, but when I try to right-click open in powershell it quickly opens and then closes. I can see red error text and I think it says, "string is missing the terminator".

Here's the code .

```
Copy-Item 'C:\Users\Me\Documents' 'E:\Me\ImportantDocuments\Backup\' -recurse -force
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call Powershell directly like that in the task scheduler.
Do the following:
For the task scheduler "Start a program" specify:
`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
Yes, i know it says v1.0, but this never changes, i.e. still works with version 4.

For the optional aguments, specify:
`-Command &"{ Copy-item C:\temp\source.txt C:\temp\destination.txt }"`
Or, you can specify a ps script file, with `-File C:\temp\test.ps1`
[image]